# Open file in Firefox by clicking on a file path within Notepad++ editor

Tags: notepad++

We have a log file that outputs some file names like
    `C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Company1\HttpResponse-2012.04.16_14.33.51_499-Error.html`.

We use Notepad++ v5.8.7 to look at the log files.

Is it possible to just *click* or *Ctrl+Click* or to use other shortcuts to open the file (e.g. C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Company1\HttpResponse-2012.04.16_14.33.51_499-Error.html) in Firefox?

Are there plug-ins that supports that?

Up to now I need to

1. Select file path
2. Select Run->Open file
   -> File is opened in Notepad++
3. Select Run->Launch in Firefox
   -> File is shown by Firefox

Is there a shorter way to show the file in Firefox?

Comment: A `.html` file is supposed to open in your default web browser. Do you want to launch the log file without opening notepad++ first? Can you please make it little clear?

Comment: Yes, we open our log file in Notepad++. The log file lists some links to local html files. When we want to open one of these HTML files in Firefox we would prefer to open it in an easy way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the following line (command) in the Run (by pressing F5 or ALT+R+R) window of Notepad++.

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "$(CURRENT_WORD)"
```

The following figure will make it clear. 
[image]

You need to select the link and then it will open in firefox. 
You may need to change the path depending on where  firefox.exe is located. You may also choose the shortcut accordingly. (I used CTRL+INS since this was available).